# Button doesn't work, no issues are found, did I write something wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace tofuchanfra 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            wplayer.URL = @"C:\Users\Cristi\Music\DOOM CROSSING Eternal HorizonsMusic Video feat. Natalia Natchan.mp3";
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a Winforms program that plays an audio file, there is no error when debugging but when I fire it up and press the button, nothing plays.

I have tried to make another button and use that one but it still doesn't work, any help?

Comment: Events handlers in C# are not convention based (merely having a button control called `button1` and a method called `button1_Click` isn't enough - you have to wire them up). I'm guessing you didn't wire up the event in the control's Properties panel.

Comment: Try playing a .wav file and see if it works. Also try putting the mp3 on a path without spaces and without spaces in name.

Comment: Also it seems online it should be `wplayer.Controls.Play();` , note the capitals

Comment: And also you cant be sure Windows Media Player is installed on the machine, so beware of using it on other pcs.

Comment: First try to check if the button, by itself, works or not (you can use ```MessageBox.Show("")``` ). then we will be able to help you better, by knowing if it's the button or the other code.